# filter on input in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

How to write some `@Pipe` for filtering (in `<input>` tag) the data in table?

```
    <tr *ngFor='let list of lists'>
      <td><input type="" name="" value=""></td>
      <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ list.location }}</td>
      <td>{{ list.type_id }}</td>
    <tr>
```

The data i get from api with http service:

```
getServices(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

UPD:

this is my service component:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable() 
export class TableComponentService{
    private _url = 'http://101.496.222.511:8080/api/v1/10';

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    names:string[];
    getServices(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

and this is a table component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TableComponentService } from './table.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'tablecomponent',
    templateUrl: 'app/table.template.html',
    providers: [TableComponentService]
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
    lists: any[];

    constructor(private _service: TableComponentService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getServices()
            .subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists)
    }

}
```

Comment: can u explain what do you mean by filering exactly

Comment: @Atal Kishore in `<input>` tag i write some symbol , and then find full word. For example, write A - and then find Alpha

Comment: why do u want to use pipe instead on change event just call the getservices() and store the value received in an variable and display the result wherever you want by using the variable

Comment: @Atal Kishore and how fo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pipe use keyup event to call the getservices() and store the value received in an variable and display the result wherever you want by using the variable

**Example**

```
 <tr *ngFor='let list of lists'>
      <td><input type="" name="" value="" (keyup)="getServices()" >
       <span *ngFor='let name of names'>{{name }}</span>
      </td>
      <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ list.location }}</td>
      <td>{{ list.type_id }}</td>
 <tr>


names:string[];
getServices(): Observable<any> {
    this.names=this._http.get(this._url)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

EDIT:-

make _service public in constructor

`constructor(public_service: TableComponentService)`

then in html

`<input type="" name="" value="" (keyup)="_service.getServices()" >`

Comment: thanks for quick answer, now, i have this error `core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Error in app/table.template.html:31:69 caused by: self.context.getServices is not a function`

Comment: make function as public

Comment: `public getServices(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }` like this?

Comment: getServices() is present in your component or service? can you post some code from controller as well

Comment: See the Edit portion of my Answer

Comment: you mean `constructor(public _service: TableComponentService)`? and now i dont have any errors, but when i write in `<input>` filter dosent still working yet :(

Comment: friend, help me, please